# Windows Service dependency not respected

Tags: windows-7, windows, services, windows-services, dependencies

I have two windows services installed in Windows 7 environment:

- Tomcat Webserver
- MariaDB database

These services have dependency relationship, Tomcat depends on MariaDB.

When I shutdown windows I found that the mariaDB is stopped before tomcat and not the opposite, how can this happen?
I'm sure about this stopping order because Tomcat has a database write before shutdown and it always finds a his database already stopped.

How can be sure to stop MariaDB serveronly after Tomcat service shutdown?

Comment: Don't you mean to ask how to control the order in which the services are shut down?

Comment: Yes, I want to be sure that the MariaDB server is stopped after Tomcat service. I thought to achive this with service dependencies

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information.